# How to use File::ReadAllBytes in visual c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-c++-2013

Visual Studio has a simple method "File::ReadAllBytes" that will read a file and return a byte array, but I don't know how to use it. I tried the following and they all don't work.

```
Byte arr[] = File::ReadAllBytes("file.txt");
Byte *arr = File::ReadAllBytes("file.txt");
unsigned char arr[] = File::ReadAllBytes("file.txt");
unsigned char *arr = File::ReadAllBytes("file.txt");

unsigned char *arr;
arr = File::ReadAllBytes("file.txt");
```

Comment: That's a .NET method. Are you writing in normal C++ or in C++/CLI?

Comment: Yes it is a .NET method. Sorry if the question was inaccurate, but visual studio references use the term C++ when talking about such code.

Comment: Are you using normal C++ or in C++/CLI?

Comment: I am using C++, as in the question.

Comment: It returns an `array<Byte>^`.  You could consider using the `auto` keyword, albeit that it does nothing to help you understand writing correct C++/CLI code.  You don't exactly have to read a book, assuming you understand C++, but a tutorial is not going to hurt you at all.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have been using C++/CLI methods in my C++ code and everything has been working fine so far, but probably I should read on C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

`File::ReadAllBytes` is a .NET function, so you cannot call it from C++.

You can call it from C++/CLI (Microsoft's .NET version of C++), but you have clarified that you are not using C++/CLI.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It is not true that you can't use C++/CLI functions in a regular C++ code written in Visual Studio.

Comment: @HD86 I assumed the asker doesn't want to learn a new language (even if it's close to another language) and add a dependency on .NET just for this one function.